# Sorting NumPy array with two columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following array, which contains `X` and `Y` coordinates:

```
arr = array([[ 1.,  3.],
             [ 6.,  6.],
             [ 3.,  0.],
             [ 2.,  5.],
             [ 0.,  3.],
             [ 3.,  3.],
             [ 0.,  6.]])
```

I would like to know how can I sort this array by first sorting `X` and after by sorting `Y`.

I would like something like this:

```
new_ arr = array([[ 0.,  3.],
                  [ 0.,  6.],
                  [ 1.,  3.],
                  [ 2.,  5.],
                  [ 3.,  0.],
                  [ 3.,  3.],
                  [ 6.,  6.]])
```

Comment: there's `numpy.lexsort`

Comment: @PaulPanzer thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the np lexort function, you can read more in [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)

> numpy.lexsort(keys, axis=-1) Perform an indirect sort using a sequence
>   of keys.
>
> Given multiple sorting keys, which can be interpreted as columns in a
>   spreadsheet, lexsort returns an array of integer indices that
>   describes the sort order by multiple columns. The last key in the
>   sequence is used for the primary sort order, the second-to-last key
>   for the secondary sort order, and so on. The keys argument must be a
>   sequence of objects that can be converted to arrays of the same shape.
>   If a 2D array is provided for the keys argument, it’s rows are
>   interpreted as the sorting keys and sorting is according to the last
>   row, second last row etc

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[ 1.,  3.],
             [ 6.,  6.],
             [ 3.,  0.],
             [ 2.,  5.],
             [ 0.,  3.],
             [ 3.,  3.],
             [ 0.,  6.]])
ind = np.lexsort(np.transpose(arr)[::-1])

print (arr[ind])

>>>[[ 0.  3.]
 [ 0.  6.]
 [ 1.  3.]
 [ 2.  5.]
 [ 3.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 6.  6.]]
```